# How can I print in android from any activity

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-studio-2.3

I'm trying to build an app that would print via Bluetooth to a thermal printer.

I've come across a problem: the activity where the printing occurs gets destroyed or finished with the `finish()` method. Then the app tries to print again sending new information to the printing activity, but can't, because the printer is already bonded with a previous object.

How can I print in Android from any activity I need to print, once the device is bonded to the printer?

I've read about Service but, couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You're either adding the print function to the wrong activity or shouldn't call finish we can't help you without more info

Comment: The answer is a Service.  Your Activity should launch a service which does the printing.  iA service has a lifecycle independent of the Activity it was created from, so finishing won't be a problem.  Also, if you had issues because a printer was bound to a previous Activity, then your Activity wasn't properly releasing it when it was destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Prior to finish() I stop the bluetooth adapter and device, now I can print again by creating another object. It works but, that's not an efficient way to do it, I think. Thanks again.